# How can I trim off the EXACT string starting from the left hand side in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select ltrim('xyzyxxyxyyxTech', 'xyz')
from dual
```

Result: 'Tech'

Expected result: 'yxxyxyyxTech'

How can I trim off only the exact string 'xyz' from the left hand side of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06302) function. AS below pattern, `^` is an anchor, mean start of the string. The result will replace only `xyz` at start of the string with blank.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('xyzyxxyxyyxTech', '^xyz', '') AS result
FROM dual
```